# Load Collection, save every product for himself or plain sql

Tags: performance, magento

I wrote an extension to count the product sales - goal is to get the bestsellers.

I created a new static attribute (means: I added a column to the catalog_product_entity table) for all products `items_sold`

I hook into the `sales_order_save_before` event

```
public function salesOrderSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
    $order = $observer->getOrder();

    // if the order will be created and has no id yet
    if(!$order->getId()) {
        $productIds = array();
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
            $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }

    // what to do here :-)

}
```

Now I see two ways:

1. I load the product collection, loop over all products, raise items_sold (+1) and save all the products
2. I fire a query like `UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET items_sold = items_sold + 1 WHERE entity_id IN $productIds`

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you intend to take into consideration refunds? canceled orders and so on?

Comment: at the moment no. I thought about invoiced, etc. but I don't think this is important. Sorry - the goal is to have a performant way to get the bestsellers

Comment: Maybe i am misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but why would you not use reports/product_collection for this?

Comment: @DrewHunter I can not imagine that it is a good idea to join through the order_items on the homepage. I missed more than I thought in the question - I hate this if a customer does it. The goal is a block on a main page of the shop to show the bestsellers. And querying through the orders is very slow in my opinion

Comment: One more thing - how real-time does this need to be, e.g. would a nightly or 2x daily update suffice?

Comment: You could implement block caching or otherwise to some extent.  My initial thoughts are that I would prefer sales data to be kept separate from product data.

Comment: Drew, would you post the block caching as an answer, so I can accept it? :-)

Comment: @DrewHunter , would you post the block caching as an answer, so I can accept it? :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - i have added a very basic answer.  let me know if you need anything more complete.  It should be enough to get you started though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the reports models as ever with magento there are a few ways to achieve this.  One method could be (This is the method used in adminhtml which does not take in to account complex product types):

```
$limit = 5;
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$bestSellers = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
    ->setModel('catalog/product')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->setPageSize($limit)
    ->setCurPage(1);
```

Based on your question you may be looking for the following instead:

```
$limit = 5;
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$bestSellers = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize($limit)
    ->setCurPage(1);
```

To apply block caching (this will require that the block/html tag be refreshed) also change the `cache_lifetime` to a figure you are comfortable with:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array (
        'cache_lifetime' => false,
        'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG)
    ));
}
```

You could go further and add a [custom cache tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663722/magento-custom-caching-with-admin-switch) for your module/bestsellers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think about the Magento Report System? Its a seperate Index Process thats write into Flat Tables. Go to the Admin under /admin/report_sales/bestsellers/