# Magento: where is the trigger of the custom cache?

Tags: magento, caching

In this Stackoverflow question the answer shows how to add a custom cache status: [Magento Custom Caching with admin switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663722/magento-custom-caching-with-admin-switch)

Now my question is: Where is this triggered?

**UPDATE:**
I've followed the steps as mentioned above. Now I have this code in Abstract/Service.php

```
final class COMP_NAME_Abstract_Service
{

    static private $_instance;
    private $_licenseHelpers = array();

    public function clearCache( $custom = false )
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

    public function getCache()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }   
}
```

But I have to 'call' the clearCache function somewhere, but where and how?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial I found on caching. You can use a custom `XML` file to use in your cache. This method lets other modules extend your `XML` file using `Magento`'s built in *XML configuration files merging*. Maybe it is too elaborate for what you are trying to achieve but it can certainly gives you a good idea. Look closely at the `Config.php` file. Its constructor shows how the XML file is parsed and cached. [Custom configuration files in Magento](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/08/02/custom-configuration-files-in-magento.html)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so other users will have some idea of what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Think of what happens if that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Please take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use event `adminhtml_cache_refresh_type`.
Add to event section in global.

```
<global>
  <events>
    <adminhtml_cache_refresh_type>
    <observers>
        <module_alias>
            <class>COMPNAME_MODULENAME_Model_Observer</class>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <method>cleanCacheType</method>
        </module_alias>
     </observers>
     </adminhtml_cache_refresh_type>
   </events>
</global>
```

Add this code to observer `COMP_NAME_module_name_Model_Observer`:

```
public function cleanCacheType(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   if ($observer->getData('type') == "your_cache_type"){
       //CUSTOM CODE
   }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting all selected cache tags on "adminhtml_cache_refresh_type" event

Answer (score 1):

check event **application_clean_cache** 
when clear cache like - `Mage::app()->cleanCache();`
or when system saves product etc...

and take a look on event - **adminhtml_cache_refresh_type**
when clearing cache via admin panel

and your code in observer

```
Mage::app()->getCache()->clean('all', array('my_tag'));
```

and need add some logic to Observer,
for check need refresh cache or not

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by triggerd? How you write things into this new cache?

```
Mage::app()->saveCache($data, $cacheKey, $this->getCacheTags(), $this->getCacheLifetime());
```

and the cache tags are used for deletion

Comment: I mean, when I 'check the cache options' (like: CONFIG, LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG) etc. I now also have a new one: (MYCACHE) but where can I set what it actually has to do? I think I have to extend it in the Observer...? But what should I extend.

Comment: You write things in the cache, via saveCache(), you load things from the cache via loadCache() and if the cache invalidates you call cleanCache($tag) or removeCache($id)

Comment: Thanks but I actually mean something different. When the action Refresh is choosen I want to do an action. And I'm not sure how to do this. I think I have to create an 'class COMP_NAME_Model_Rewriter_Observer' in /Model/Rewriter/Observer.php But I don't understand how I need to tell Magento to look in this class to execute the public function clearCache. (Maybe in XML?) Again, thank for you help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would think refresh means clean :-) and you define in the config.xml the tags which are cleaned. Then you can rebuild the cache in your block, model, etc. classes

Comment: Exactly, but what I don't understand is how to address them in the block, model or etc classes.

Comment: what do you mean? How to `loadCache()` or how to `saveCache()`?

Comment: Well before that I have: class COMP_NAME_Model_Observer extends ??? what would the ??? be in this case (in Observer.php)

Comment: Maybe this is more clear (what the problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052866/magento-why-is-the-public-function-in-the-observer-not-working)

Comment: I've got: 'extend adminhtml_cache_refresh_type' but that's not working :-(

Comment: Hi @HamendraSunthwal I don't understand your problem but I'm pretty sure opening a new question is a good idea :)