# Magento: why is the public function in the Observer not working?

Tags: magento

I've got 2 files for my module: etc/config.xml and Model/Observer.php

**Config.xml:**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <cache>
            <types>
                <DN_js_module module="COMP_dn_js" translate="DN Cache">
                    <label>DN Cache (JS CSS)</label>
                    <description>Refresh Javascript and CSS (DN)</description>
                    <tags>COMP_DN_JSCSS</tags>
                </DN_js_module>
            </types>
        </cache>
        <events>             
            <DN_trigger>
                <observers>
                    <comp_dncache>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>dncache/observer</class>
                        <method>setCache</method>
                    </comp_dncache>
                </observers>
            </DN_trigger>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php:**

```
class COMP_DNCache_Model_Observer extends Mage_Adminhtml_CacheController
{
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function setCache($observer){
         die('test');
    }
}
```

So, the config.xml adds an extra option to the cache list in Magento. When it's refreshed I want the public function setCache() to run and (in this case) show me the output: 'test'

Now the problem is, the setCache is not triggered and I can't get 'test' to showup :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that within your code you are dispatching event `dn_trigger`

e.g

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent(
     'dn_trigger',
     array('xyz' => $xyz, )
 );
```

In **Observer.php:**

```
class COMP_DNCache_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function setCache($observer){
         die('test');
    }
}
```